# Why is webjob log not showing proper failed message?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

[image]

I am trying to execute a manually triggered webjob. The system automatically gets failed without showing any proper failed message. I even added application insight to the program but i can't see any failed log in application insight as well.

My main application calls different interfaces and methods from different projects. I have linked all of them by adding references in my main project. I uploaded my webjob simply by using visual studio 2017 feature **Publish Azure Webjob**

App.config screenshot:
[image: App.config]

I have couple of connection to Azure file share and one for Database(Microsoft SQL Server)

When I am uploading .exe file from `bin>release` and then when i am running it this error message is showing up:
[image: When I am uploading .exe file in Azure Webjob]

Comment: If an exception occurs before the logging system is initialized due to a missing assembly for example this can happen.

Comment: But it is working fine in my local environment. How should i debug such kind of issue to see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with adding reference to class library from my console application. Although the issue still persist but now at least I know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We have reproduced the issue from our end and faced the same problem while deploying the `webjob` from Visual Studio.

But we have successfully able to run the `webjob` as you can see in the below attached screenshots for your reference.

Points to be re-checked from your end to publish the webjob to azure app service without any errors:

- Make sure after creating the webjob ->open the `app.config` file in the VS and add the below configuration properties under the `<configuration>`:

```cs
<add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="place your storage account connection string here"/>  
<add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="place your storage account connection string here"/>
```

We have used `runtime .net framework` as `Version=v4.7.2` in Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

**Note**: copy and paste the same storage account connection string for both the above properties in `app.config` file i.e. **AzureWebJobsDashboard** and **AzureWebJobsStorage**.

- After adding these properties in the `app.config` file -> save it and right click on the solution explorer tab in Visual studio and build:

[image]

- Then publish to azure from the solution explorer tab in VS:

[image]

- Now go to the **App Service** in azure portal and select **webjobs** then **run** the webjob and click on the **logs** tab to show the results page as shown below:

[image]

- If the webjob gets successfully deployed then you can see the status as **Running** like in the below screenshot:

[image]

- If there are any Errors after the deployment then you can see the error messages by clicking the `toggle output` screen and troubleshoot based on the error message like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i am confused because i got reference to couple of file storage in azure and one database connection to Microsoft SQL Server. I have added the scrrenshot of my web.config to the question.

Comment: BTW I have tried adding keys in my app.config file but the same error still showing up. Isn't there any way to find where it is actually failing?